# NoClassDefFound error Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Iam trying to run my Android project but I get the following error :-

```
01-01 13:28:06.775: E/AndroidRuntime(1812): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mapps.dailystatusupdater.StatusUpdater
01-01 13:28:06.775: E/AndroidRuntime(1812):     at com.mapps.dailystatusupdater.SplashScreen$RefreshTokenTask.onPostExecute(SplashScreen.java:253)
01-01 13:28:06.775: E/AndroidRuntime(1812):     at com.mapps.dailystatusupdater.SplashScreen$RefreshTokenTask.onPostExecute(SplashScreen.java:1)
```

SpashScreen.java

```
private class RefreshTokenTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //some code
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, StatusUpdater.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
        }


    }
```

AndroidManifest.java

```
<activity
            android:name="com.mapps.dailystatusupdater.StatusUpdater"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

I updated my ADT to from 22.X to 23.0 .I have tried Cleaning project, restarting eclipse, Exporting my Android private libraries and nothing works.

[image]

[image]

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to install Android SDK Build-tools in Android SDK manager.

Comment: I currently have Build-tools Rev 17 installed

Comment: I installed the build tools rev 21.1.2. Now when I run my project I get this error `[2015-01-01 13:42:16 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
[2015-01-01 13:42:16 - DailyStatusUpdater] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
`

Comment: Looks like this might have been the problem. I also unchecked the android-support-v4.jar that I was exporting. Thanks for your answer

Comment: You were getting that error due to multiple occurences of the `android-support-v4.jar` library. Anyway, thanks for accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

goto android sdk manager  make sure you have android build tools installed.

Comment: I installed the build tools rev 21.1.2. Now when I run my project I get this error `[2015-01-01 13:42:16 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
[2015-01-01 13:42:16 - DailyStatusUpdater] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;

Comment: This error can happen if you have two jars that contains the same class names.

Comment: Do one more thing create New work space and create sample project in that. After it works perfectly then import your existing project in that new workspace

Comment: Looks like adding build tools did the trick. I also unchecked the android-support-v4.jar that I was exporting. Thanks for your answer and time. Upovoting your answer.